# Show different layout on left & right swipe in 47deg/swipeList view?

Tags: android, android-listview

```
How to show different layout on right & left swipe.
```

With  swipeBackView we can show same layout on both left & right swipe of a row of list view .
I have to display 2 different layout say layout A on left swipe & layout B on right swipe.

```
github link of 47deg/swipelistview:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Here is XML:

    <com.example.swipelistview.SwipeListView
     android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
     swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
     swipe:swipeMode="both"  />
```

In xml we can set swipeBackView to layout id to be displayed that will display same layout on both right & left swipe.But how to show different layout on left & right swipe.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I suggest you could use fragments

Comment: Have found any solution to that?